# ASP.NET MVC CRUD with LocalDb savechanges error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I'm using VS 2015 and I created an ASP.NET MVC project and added a couple things (log in and register did work fine with Localdb called `MyDatabase.mdf`) that did work.

CRUD only create function in db the rest will come later.

But now I can't get this work. Inside the LocalDb called `MyDatabase.mdf`, I have created another table called `Amsterdam`:

[MyDatabase.mdf][1]

And this is my `MainDbContext.cs` - here I added

```
public DbSet<Amsterdam> Amsterdam { get; set; }
```

And in my `Home` folder I wrote `Amsterdam.cshtml` like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyFirstWebsite.Models.Amsterdam>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Amsterdam";
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
}

<h2>@username's Bestellijst Amsterdam</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <span>Enter new item: </span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="new_item"/>
    <br/>
    <span>Public post?</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_public"/><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Item"/>
}
<br/>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Id Bestelling</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Details Bestelling</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Time - Ontvangen Bestelling</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Time - Verzonden Bestelling</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Edit</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Delete</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Public Post</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home")/">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")/">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in my `Models` folder I created `Amsterdam.cs` which looks like this:

```
namespace MyFirstWebsite.Models
{
    public class Amsterdam
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Details { get; set; }

        public string Date_Posted { get; set; }
        public string Time_Posted { get; set; }
        public string Date_Edited { get; set; }
        public string Time_Edited { get; set; }
        public string Public { get; set; }
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my `Controllers` folder my `HomeController` looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Amsterdam()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Amsterdam(Amsterdam list)
{
    string timeToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    string dateToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new MainDbContext())
        {
            Claim sessionEmail = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
            string userEmail = sessionEmail.Value;
            var userIdQuery = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == userEmail).Select(u => u.Id);
            var userId = userIdQuery.ToList();

            var dbAmsterdam = db.Amsterdam.Create();
            dbAmsterdam.Details = list.Details;
            dbAmsterdam.Date_Posted = dateToday;
            dbAmsterdam.Time_Posted = timeToday;
            dbAmsterdam.User_Id = userId[0];
            db.Amsterdam.Add(dbAmsterdam);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect format has been placed");
    }

    return View();
}
```

I know I got close because my register does work but I can't get my CRUD for `Amsterdam` to work. When I click ok as shown in the screenshot (when I click on Ad Item):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsGws.png

I get an error

> DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6kYP.png

Comment: It also says "See the Inner exception" . Did you ? What does it say ?

Comment: {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Amsterdams'."}

Comment: `db.Amsterdam.Create()` ? What does that do ?

Comment: creating the Amsterdam table within the code base.

Comment: It did work i changed the NOT NULL to NULL and worked Shyju thanks for the inner exception thing did not look at that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that EF is doing pluralization of your object name to define the table name in the database (from the error - `Invalid object name dbo.Amsterdams`).

If your table name is `Amsterdam` (singular, without the trailing "s"), then add this data annotation to your model class:

```
[Table("Amsterdam")]
public class Amsterdam
{         
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

And if you want to turn off that pluralization of table names completely, you can add this line to your `MainDbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
{
    dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```